# How to paginate filtered data with firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

when I filter my firestore data I still get a large subset and would like to paginate through this data. but the default firestore paginate queries (startAfter/endAfter) cannot be combined whit the where clause in my experience.

I know how to filter data in firestore and I also know how to paginate. but i'd love to combine both these to features, would someone please help me with achieving this. or atleast how to restructure my data if need be.

```
   ref
      .where(this.query.filter.field,'==', this.query.filter.item ) 
      .orderBy(this.query.field)  //filter spoils previous where clause   
      .limit(this.query.limit)
      .startAfter(lastProduct)
}})

//where clause and startAfter clause dont work together when I use orderBy alone the query works but thats now what I want.

//error code when the ubove code is run

core.js:9110 ERROR FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're missing an index for the query.  Follow the link given in the error messages to the console and create it, then you should be able to execute the query.